# Is possible automated login Guest OS by powercli api 6.5?

Tags: vmware, powercli

I am a new guy with powercli. I can't find these related information on 6.5 SDK Document. Could someone can answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be more specific.  Not sure what you are asking here.

You can open the console window via script:

http://blogs.vmware.com/PowerCLI/2013/10/opening-the-virtual-machine-remote-console-through-powercli.html

This allows you to acccess the VM as if you were logged into the vSphere console.

Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: Sorry, it isn't my question. I'd like ask it's possible like VM Workstation.
To configure Autologin for a selected virtual machine, select VM > Settings, click the Options tab, and select Autologin.